# Loop selection to get the missing data entries in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

Hi I am developing an application to retrieve data from SQL Serevr to MySQL by interval of 15 minutes.

I have 10 tables for 10 different stations.

I defined two string arrays for this as below.

```
private readonly string[] _tables =
 {
  "RAW_T01", "RAW_T02", "RAW_T03", "RAW_T04", "RAW_T05",
  "RAW_ RAW_T06", "RAW_ RAW_T07", "RAW_ RAW_T08", " RAW_T09", "RAW_ RAW_T10"
 };

private readonly string[] _stations =
 {
  "Clinton", "Franklin", "Madison", "Washington", "Chester",
  "Marion", "Greenville", "Springfield", "Georgetown", "Salem"
 };
```

also for passing starting date.

```
string time = "2010-03-05 16:00:00";
DateTime tempTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
```

And I have a function to retrieve data and check exist and insert if not exist.

```
private void CheckSsMissingDate()
 {
  for (var i = 0; i < _tables.Length; i++)
   {
    var temp = _tables[i];
    station = _stations[i];
    while(DateTime.Parse(time) <= DateTime.Now)
     {
      var ssCon = OpenSQLConnection();
      var cmd =
      new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (1) Date_Time,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,
                     Value5,Value6,"+ "Value7,Value8,Value9 from "+temp+" where
                     Date_Time >='" + tempTime + "'",ssCon);
      var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      var count = 0;
      while (dr.Read())
       {
        ssChkDate = (dr["Date_Time"].ToString());
        conssChkDate = DateTime.Parse(ssChkDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        tempTime = Convert.ToDateTime(ssChkDate);
        tempTime = tempTime.AddMinutes(15);
        TValue1 = (dr["Value1"].ToString());
        TValue2 = (dr["Value2"].ToString());
        TValue3 = (dr["Value3"].ToString());
        TValue4 = (dr["Value4"].ToString());
        TValue5 = (dr["Value5"].ToString());
        TValue6 = (dr["Value6"].ToString());
        TValue7 = (dr["Value7"].ToString());
        TValue8 = (dr["Value8"].ToString());
        TValue9 = (dr["Value9"].ToString());
        //check for data exist in table or not
        if (CheckMsMissingDate(conssChkDate) == false)
         {
          //insert if data is missing
          InsertMissing(conssChkDate,station,TValue1,TValue2,
                         TValue3,TValue4,TValue5,TValue6,TValue7,TValue8,TValue9);
          count = count + 1;
         }
       }//end of dataReader while loop
       dr.Close();
       ssCon.Close();
       updateCount.Text = count + @" Missing Records added.";
    }//end of date time check while loop
  }//end of for loop
}//end of CheckSsMissingDate
```

Here when I execute this function I am getting only first stations missing values not getting other stations. Not getting why while loop run only for first table only.

Comment: Check what are you getting in dr..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code.
First of all you need to stop the while loop working when Read() gone empty like below.

```
//write this after
 }//end of dataReader while loop
time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString();
```

Here we are doing while condition false and then after `for (var i = 0; i < _tables.Length; i++)` we are checking the date and time is it greater than `DateTime.Now` if yes it means we set value is in `time` then you can just assign your starting date time like below.

```
if (DateTime.Parse(time)>DateTime.Now)
{
 time = "2010-03-05 16:00:00";
 tempTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
}
```

That’s all. It will definitely work.